# Need an explanation on wording of `kevent` filter

Tags: c, freebsd, manpage, kqueue, kevent

I have following lines for `kevent` in the `man`:

```
  EVFILT_TIMER        Establishes an arbitrary timer identified by ident.
                     When adding a timer, data specifies the moment to
                     fire the timer (for NOTE_ABSTIME) or the timeout
                     period.  The timer will be periodic unless EV_ONESHOT
                     or NOTE_ABSTIME is specified.  On return, data
                     contains the number of times the timeout has expired
                     since the last call to kevent().  For non-monotonic
                     timers, this filter automatically sets the EV_CLEAR
                     flag internally.

                     The filter accepts the following flags in the fflags
                     argument:

                     NOTE_SECONDS      data is in seconds.

                     NOTE_MSECONDS     data is in milliseconds.

                     NOTE_USECONDS     data is in microseconds.

                     NOTE_NSECONDS     data is in nanoseconds.

                     NOTE_ABSTIME      The specified expiration time is
                                       absolute.

                     If fflags is not set, the default is milliseconds.
                     On return, fflags contains the events which triggered
                     the filter.
```

Now, I do not understand the last line:

> On return, fflags contains the events which triggered the filter.

I mean literally, I do not understand the sentence. The event by the definition is a struct. How can `fflags` contain "events"?

**Update**

The return value of `fflags` of `EVFILT_TIMER` is the same as that was passed in. Thanks to OP of accepted answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the **`FreeBSD-13.0-RELEASE-p11`** sources:

From what we see in `/usr/src/sys/kern/kern_event.c` (as an example of use):

```
static int
filt_proc(struct knote *kn, long hint)
{
    struct proc *p;
    u_int event;

    p = kn->kn_ptr.p_proc;
    if (p == NULL) /* already activated, from attach filter */
        return (0);

    /* Mask off extra data. */
    event = (u_int)hint & NOTE_PCTRLMASK;

    /* If the user is interested in this event, record it. */
    if (kn->kn_sfflags & event)
        kn->kn_fflags |= event;

    /* Process is gone, so flag the event as finished. */
    if (event == NOTE_EXIT) {
        kn->kn_flags |= EV_EOF | EV_ONESHOT;
        kn->kn_ptr.p_proc = NULL;
        if (kn->kn_fflags & NOTE_EXIT)
            kn->kn_data = KW_EXITCODE(p->p_xexit, p->p_xsig);
        if (kn->kn_fflags == 0)
            kn->kn_flags |= EV_DROP;
        return (1);
    }

    return (kn->kn_fflags != 0);
}
```

The value of the `u_int event` above in one from some defined in `/usr/include/sys/event.h` which are `u_int` too.

So, the `fflags` is used as **input** and **output** as well as defined in the man page:

> The predefined system filters are listed below.  Arguments may be passed to and from the filter via the fflags and data fields in the kevent structure.

You will find the `event` referred by `fflags` in `/usr/include/sys/event.h`

Comment: Having read Linux sources, and I find 'em not easy to comprehend, I was ready to face a similar issue with FreeBSD. The above mentioned code is a good example of a clear and human readable code. Your answer did a right thing to point me to read a source of my system. Doing so is much faster than scumming through countless web sources for the documentation.

Comment: BTW, the file has a mention of a few filters that are not documented in the `man` page for `kevent`. One of the not documented filter flags seem to must have work as is.

Comment: @user14063792468: thank you really appreciate. If you want to go deeper, you have a complete chapter on kevent io in ["The Design and Implementation of the FreeBSD System](https://www.pearson.com/us/higher-education/program/Mc-Kusick-Design-and-Implementation-of-the-Free-BSD-Operating-System-The-2nd-Edition/PGM224032.html) - in III 7.1 Descriptor Management and Services. One of the best book on FreeBSD, perhaps google it ...

Comment: I'm sure that above is a good read. But I'm more focused on a practical usage of a system. I mean, task to implementation usage. The FreeBSD team is great tho. If one day I will find a way to monetize my knowledge, I will spend some money on FreeBSD project. No luck, as of now ;)